# JQuery and Ajax: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a particular request from website by using variable in the URL and AJAX to display JSON. It seems like everything is working but there is an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". A debugger points to JQuery file and the line in my script ($.ajax.success).

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}

$(document).ready(function () {

  var output = $('#news');
  var postid = getQueryVariable('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.domain.pro/api/get_post/?post_id=' + postid + '&post_type=news',
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {
       $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
        var news = '<div>' + item.title + '</div><div>' + item.content + '</div><hr/>';

        output.append(news);


      });
    },
    error: function () {
      output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
  });
})
```

Could you please help me to sort this out? Really appreciate your halp.

Comment: Which line does it highlight?

Comment: Confirm that `data` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Also, jsonp + POST doesn't make much sense. you can't POST using a `<script src="http://www.cityfacts.pro/api/get_post/?post_id=12341234&post_type=news"></script>` which is what jQuery does internally for jsonp requests.

Comment: what you have in query variable before split?

Comment: inside you `each` function you are re-declaring the news variable. remove var and add +. should be `news+=`

Comment: Hi Fermin, it highlights line 18 - ($.ajax.success)

Comment: Hi Kevin, it supposed to be JSON. I have removed POST as well but still got the same error.

Comment: It seems like you are not getting any info returned from your AJAX call, hence the undefined data

Comment: please validate the data. Seems data.posts does not exist at.

Comment: Hi Matanya, I have removed var and added + but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: axel.michel the data exists please follow a link I dropped a few lines above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should validate your data before performing operations on it:

**UPDATED**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.domain.pro/api/get_post/?post_id=' + postid + '&post_type=news',
            async: false,
            callback: 'callback',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data, status) {
               if(data != undefined && data.post != undefined){
                 $('#news').append('<div>' + data.post.title + '</div><div>' + data.post.content + '</div><hr/>');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
              output.html('<h1 class="error">There was an error loading the data.</h2>');
            }
          });
```

Comment: Hi TNCodeMonkey,
I have validated the data...but issue is the same...Dunno what to do to be honest...

Comment: @qqruza I would try swapping out the $.each and do a for loop.  Begin by stripping your operations down to the bare necessities, then build back up until the error is shown.

Comment: TNCodeMonkey, If you could kindly help me with amending the code I would be really appreciate your help. I am sorry for asking just started with JQuery...Thank you.

Comment: Thank you TNCCodeMonkey, but I have got another error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Pointed to "error: function () {"

Comment: TNCodeMonkey thank you. Now it says Semantic Issue: Unexpected token ',' - reffers to line 17 of your code

Comment: @qqruza Updated again, forgot a '}'

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, it seems the feed is retrieved but it is not displayed on the page.

Comment: @qqruza Looking at the data, from http://www.cityfacts.pro/api/get_post/?post_id=1276&post_type=news, the variable name is "post", not "posts" (as displayed in your code)

Comment: Yes, you are right and I have changed posts to post and it didn't make any difference. Have you got any other thoughts. Really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @qqruza I've updated the post again, stripping any variables outside the scope of the ajax object.  If this doesn't work, I might be out of ideas...

Comment: If I change line - var postid = getQueryVariable('id'); to
var postid = '1267';
It does show the data.

Comment: I have done it succesfully TNCCodeMonkey. Thanks a lot, you're a very good developer!

Comment: @qqruza That's great, I am glad that we could get it resolved!

Answer (score 1):

you applying $.each on data.post which could be undefined if your data is null. $.each expects and array or collection that is why you getting an error for length. since your data is null hence data.post would be undefined. you could check before applying $.each like

```
if(typeof data == "object" && data.post)
    //Your code here.
```

this check should be applied whenever you expect some data from ajax.

Comment: Hi Rahul,
I have done the check but it didn't help unfortunately. Have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell me what type of data you are expecting?

Comment: Hi Rahul, if you can help me to amend the code I would really appreciate your help.